given $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$ prove that $\frac{a^2-c^2}{b^2-d^2}=\frac{ac}{bd}$
given $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$ prove that $\frac{a^2-c^2}{b^2-d^2}=\frac{ac}{bd}$
i'm grade 7 so i need to solve using series of equal ratios and reasoning about equal ratios
I tried using $\frac{a}{b}=k$ so that $a=kb$, $c=kd$ but i couldn't do anything

This is hard to read.  Do you mean $\frac ab=\frac cd\implies \frac {a^2-c^2}{b^2-d^2}=\frac {ac}{bd}$?

Hi! Welcome to Math StackExchange

We have $$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d} = k \implies a=bk, c=dk$$
Then, $$\frac{a^2 - c^2}{b^2 - d^2} = k^2\frac{b^2 - d^2}{b^2 - d^2} = k^2 = \frac{ac}{bd}$$

Can you explain like I'm five about why a^2-c^2/b^2-d^2=k^2 x b^2-d^2/b^2-d^2?

So if you substitute $a=bk$ and $c=dk$ in the expression, you get $\frac{b^2 k^2 - d^2 k^2}{b^2 - k^2}$. Now, if you factor out $k^2$ you get what you want

$$\dfrac{a^2}{c^2}=\dfrac{b^2}{d^2}\Longrightarrow\frac{a^2-c^2}{c^2}=\frac{b^2-d^2}{d^2}\Longrightarrow\frac{a^2-c^2}{b^2-d^2}=\frac{c^2}{d^2}=\frac{c}{d}\times\frac{c}{d}=\frac{c}{d}\times\frac{a}{b}$$

You need to assume $a\neq \pm c$ and $b\neq \pm d$, otherwise
$$
\frac{a^2-c^2}{b^2-d^2}=\frac00
$$
is undefined.
Given that, remember that
$$
\frac ab=\frac cd\quad\text{means}\quad ad=bc.
$$
Using this we have
$$
(b^2-d^2)ac=b^2ac-d^2ac=ba^2d-dbc^2=(a^2-c^2)bd
$$
which in turn proves
$$
\frac{a^2-c^2}{b^2-d^2}=\frac{ac}{bd}.
$$

You nicely noted that the vital conditions at first!+

We need only assume $,b\neq \pm d,,$ as is clearer using only fractions as in my answer. $\ \ $

$\displaystyle\frac{a}b=\frac{c}d\,\Rightarrow\, \frac{ac}{bd}=\color{#0a0}{\frac{a^2}{b^2}} = \color{#c00}{\frac{i\:\!c^2}{i\:\!d^2}} \,\overset{\color{darkorange}m_{\phantom |}\!}=\, \frac{\color{#0a0}{a^2}+\color{#c00}{i\:\!c^2}}{\color{#0a0}{b^2}+\color{#c00}{i\:\!d^2}}\,$ by $\,\color{darkorange}m$ =mediant, if $\,b^2\!\neq\!-id^2\ (\color{#c00}{i=-1}\,$ in OP)  $\ \ $

My ancient friend B. D.. Nice to see you.
